# Java Swing: Possible to send robot keyboard input to specific JFrame windows?

Tags: java, swing, awt, awtrobot

I am using a third party java library which spawns new JFrame windows. How do I make java.awt.Robot to send clicks and keyboard inputs to that specific window when it appears? I would run it in a separate thread so that other activities could be performed on the main application while robot is sending inputs to the specific JFrame window.

Note, I don't have api access to the process which spawns this JFrame window.

Currently, when the that JFrame window is minimized or closed, the robot will continue sending inputs to whatever current JFrame window is visible.

Comment: how do you get hold of the spawned frame?

Comment: not sure what you mean? it is triggered by an event produced by the library itself during runtime. there's no api to access this event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get all the frames launched by your application:

```
Frame[] frames = JFrame.getFrames();
//find the frame your looking for and call click(frame)
```

Click on the center of a component

```
click(Component c){

//get center 
Dimension size = c.getSize();
Point center = new Point(size.width/2, size.height/2);

//you might want to check if the component is showing.

Robot.mouseMove(center.getX(), center.getY());
Robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);

}
```